# XCode automatic device provisioning - Distribution Certificate failed, Portal says: Error

Tags: ios, distribution, provisioning

So this just started happening now, I have no idea as to why. I needed a new Distribution certificate because my old on expired. So following the steps I created a Certificate Signing Request and submitted it to the portal.

After submitting the request comes up as 'issued' then disappears.
Clicking on the 'History' tab says the request returned an Error and nothing else.

So try a different method, using Automatic Provisioning via XCode
open Xcode's "Window" menu > Organizer > Devices tab > "Provisioning Profile" sidebar under Library. Check the "Automatic Device Provisioning" checkbox and click the "Refresh" button.

it says 'You don't have a distribution certificate, want to submit a request?'
I say yes and nothing happens.

Then Clicking on the 'History' on iOS Provisioning profile tab says the request returned an Error again...

I actually suspect something is wrong on Apple's end here...

Comment: The same thing is happening for me... a problem on Apple's end could be legit

Comment: The same issue here... Really bad timing...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll try again later

Comment: Theres a heap of people on the dev forums with the same issue aswell. [http://devforums.apple.com/community/ios/distribution](http://devforums.apple.com/community/ios/distribution)

Comment: Hmm your description on how to reach that "You don't have a dist cert, wanna submit a request?" is different for me. It's in the Organizer, but under TEAMS>"Your team">and on this page hit Refresh down right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue was on Apples end, now resolved